# spss significance asterisk (for graphs)

Tags: spss

I can't seem to find any way to automatically add significance asterisks on graphs in spss (v. 23), either by syntax or GUI.

I tried searching the syntax documentation (ftp://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/analytics/spss/documentation/statistics/23.0/en/client/Manuals/IBM_SPSS_Statistics_Command_Syntax_Reference.pdf), but couldn't find it (I may not be searching correctly ... it's a 2,000 pages document).The spss forum is not responsive. Any suggestions? Thanks!!

P.S.
I'm most interested in it for bar-graphs, but also generally, for any kind of graph.

Comment: There is not any way to do this generally - you need to set up the hypothesis test first. If you give a specific example someone can probably show you how to do it in code.

Comment: Thank you Andy! Sorry if I wasn't clear, I mean after testing a hypothesis. Say I have a simple one way ANOVA:

Comment: Sorry, clicked enter too soon and I don't have editing privileges, here's the rest of my comment:

Comment: Say I have a simple one way ANOVA, with the following syntax:

ONEWAY VAR00001 BY group 
  /STATISTICS DESCRIPTIVES 
  /PLOT MEANS 
  /MISSING ANALYSIS 
  /POSTHOC=LSD ALPHA(0.05).

(To be precise, in this case I would actually build a bar graph for the result, because as is it give a line graph. The syntax is too long for a single comment, I'll add it as another comment here to follow)

Comment: Syntax for the bar graph: 


* Chart Builder. 
GGRAPH 
  /GRAPHDATASET NAME="graphdataset" VARIABLES=group MEANSE(VAR00001, 1)[name="MEAN_VAR00001" 
    LOW="MEAN_VAR00001_LOW" HIGH="MEAN_VAR00001_HIGH"] MISSING=LISTWISE REPORTMISSING=NO 
  /GRAPHSPEC SOURCE=INLINE. 
BEGIN GPL 
  SOURCE: s=userSource(id("graphdataset")) 
  DATA: group=col(source(s), name("group"), unit.category()) 
  DATA: MEAN_VAR00001=col(source(s), name("MEAN_VAR00001")) 
  DATA: LOW=col(source(s), name("MEAN_VAR00001_LOW")) 
  DATA: HIGH=col(source(s), name("MEAN_VAR00001_HIGH"))

Comment: GUIDE: axis(dim(1), label("group")) 
  GUIDE: axis(dim(2), label("Mean VAR00001")) 
  SCALE: cat(dim(1), include("1", "2", "3")) 
  SCALE: linear(dim(2), include(0)) 
  ELEMENT: interval(position(group*MEAN_VAR00001), shape.interior(shape.square)) 
  ELEMENT: interval(position(region.spread.range(group*(LOW+HIGH))), shape.interior(shape.ibeam)) 
END GPL.


Sorry again for writing this as multiple comments and thank you very much in advance for any advice!!